# Excel VBA For loop looping too early

Tags: excel, vba

When I step through the code, after the line "Cells(r_count, 5) = temp + totalDays", it goes back to the beginning of the "For c_count" loop, and the code never gets to the Next part, and so the counter is not incrimented.

```
For c_count = 7 To 42 Step 5
    For r_count = 4 To 80
        If Cells(r_count, c_count) = "pass" Then
            If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(r_count, (c_count + 1)))) Then
                If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(r_count, (c_count + 2)))) Then
                    s_date = Cells(r_count, (c_count + 1))
                    e_date = Cells(r_count, (c_count + 2))
                    totalDays = DateDiff("d", s_date, e_date)
                    temp = Cells(r_count, 5)
                    Cells(r_count, 5) = temp + totalDays
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r_count
Next c_count
```

I have to be overseeing something stupid in my code.  Should I make my IF statements into one instead of multiple statements?  Any help?

Comment: What is temp + totalDays equal to?

Comment: user1932554 Please add step on below line `code` For r_count = 4 To 80

Comment: Hiten004, I tried the step 1 and it did the same thing.

Comment: melanie, temp + totalDays equals the correct number. (What ever is stored in the cell(temp) and the difference in dates).  but then it goes back to the 'For c_count...' and starts again, with the same c_count and r_count numbers.

Comment: temp + totalDays value higher then 80 ??

Comment: after sever loops it gets there.  but no, if all works properly, it shouldn't go above maybe 15

Comment: so the code says if its passed and has a start and end date then calc the difference between them and adding this onto the last row of the block. Why are you using step 5? You have blocks of data horizontally across your spreadsheet and also vertically down up to row 80?

Comment: place `debug.print r_count` below all your end ifs, run the code, and see if r_count is incrementing in your immediate window. The structure of your loop should work.

Comment: check to see if you have an error handler active, or place `On Error Goto 0` just before your loop, to see if an error is occurring, and the code is set to go back to the start of the loop if an error occurs

Comment: I'm assuming it's because this code is inside a Worksheet_Change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this code being called by the Worksheet_Change event by any chance? I'm assuming so because you say on the `Cells(r_count, 5) = temp + totalDays` line it goes back to the beginning - this is because this line sets the cell's value hence triggering the Worksheet_Change event and that's also why it eventually finishes.

If so then you can set Application.EnableEvents to False while updates are carried out (actually Philip's suggestion). For example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ....your code here....

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: no need for a global variable. Look at 
`Application.EnableEvents`

Comment: Yes, good point. I'm used to using a global variable as EnableEvents doesn't work for UserForm control events, but this is more appropriate here. Have edited my answer accordingly